# No communication between index.html and app.component.html

Tags: html, css, node.js, angular, asp.net-core

I just created a new Angular App (version 15) in asp.net Core through command ng new projectname. It just created a project in physical location but the linking between Index.html and app.component.html is not there. I have not did any change in code, its the code that generated through command line command.
I am sharing my code.

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FullStackUI</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FullStack.UI';
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<head>
</head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">FullStack.UI</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

After Running App
[image]

Please help me to fix my these two issue.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jQUs.png) First issue that browser is showing navigation but it's not picking the style that i have added inside index.html page.

[2] Why url is showing http://localhost:54456/src/app/app.component.html url. I want to show under this url http://localhost:54456/

Please help me I am new to Angular.

Comment: As it can be read in the docs, you need to execute `ng serve` to run the application locally: https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#run-the-application It looks like you opened the `app.component.html` file via your IDE, which does not work for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to run this application through Browser that's why its showing no linking between index.html and app.component.html. Right answer is

1. Navigate to the workspace folder, such as my-app.
2. Run the following command:

[image]

Check this for [reference](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local#run-the-application)